# building shared module between applications windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm developing multiple windows 10 applications. and I have Inbox module which will be shared between all applications. this module like standalone project contains classes, xaml pages. How can I build this module to reuse it in all my applications? I don't need to copy, paste.
is windows runtime component suitable for this or which technique?

Comment: can you please show your effort?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating it as a UWP portable class library. You can then, if you wish, [create it as a Nuget package](http://docs.nuget.org/create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package) which you can share publicly or just use yourself in your own apps as is.

I do this for my own applications as, like yourself, I share code across my apps.

Comment: No problem at all @rihanahashem. Always happy to help out :)